# Binding or Style setter to get the default value of another control Type's property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

While this a generic question and I would like to ask if it is possible to do this for any scenario, my specific problem is that I want to create a datagrid header which looks like this:

```
.------.-----------------.--------.
|      |       Name      |        |
| SNo. |-----------------|  Age   |
|      | First  | Second |        |
|------|--------|--------|--------|
|1     |  Joe   | Montana|   96   |
|2     | Mario  | Luigi  |   69   |
'------'------'----------'--------'
```

However, I cant seem to get a border under "Name" cell which has the same borderbrush similar to the datagrid's default headers.

Is there something like (hypothetical syntax):

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding ElementType={x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}, Path=BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" >
   <TextBlock Text="Name" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
</Border>
```

If you could do something like this, you can just bind to a property's value of any control type and if it changes with theme, that would be Christmas!

**EDIT:** I am obviously looking for a xaml solution...I can ofcourse hack around in code-behind myself.

Thanks in advance!